# Verilog Code to determine output based on priority

Tags: verilog

I am trying to make a ring topology for a multirate data bus. I am not getting any idea how to get outputs at a node based on priority of the data packets. Suppose I want to get packets from a node in a ring. I want to get packets based on their priority. Can any one guide me how do I write verilog code for this thing. I tried to write nested if else condition like below.

```
module demux0(
input clock,
input reset,
input [43:0]in,
output reg [43:0]out0,
output reg [43:0]out1
);

always @(posedge clock)
    begin
        if(reset)
            begin
                out0<=0;
                out1<=0;
            end
        else if(in[3:0]==4'b0000 && in[13:4]==10'b0000000001) //so nested if else to gain the priority
            begin
                out1<=in; //so the packet with the highest priority goes to the output
                if(in[3:0]==4'b0000 && in[13:4]==10'b0000000010) //check the second priority packet
                    begin
                        out1<=in;
                        if(in[3:0]==4'b0000 && in[13:4]==10'b0000000100)
                            begin
                                out1<=in;
                                if(in[3:0]==4'b0000 && in[13:4]==10'b0000001000)
                                    begin
                                        out1<=in;
                                    end
                            end
                    end
            end
        else
            begin
                out0<=in;
            end
    end
endmodule
```

So here is a demux which selects output 1 if input bits in[3:0] and in[13:4] are matched else output 0 is selected. 
But the problem with this code is that the ring is clocked so if at one clock cycle I get my packet with highest priority which is 10'b0000000001 and after 3 clock cycles I get my second highest priority packet which is 10'b0000000010 here then my nested if else loop is not going to executed. 
Can anyone tell me how do I do it?

Comment: Not sure I follow your logic. If `in[13:4]==10'b0000000001`, then you'll never reach `in[13:4]==10'b0000000010`. So you can't nest a check for the latter inside a check for the former. If you're trying to describe priority in any HDL then you can just use (not nested) if-else statements, with the higher-priority conditions being present earlier in the list. I think you're confused - neither your text nor your code describe a demux.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If you see closely, the demux selects out 1 if in=4'b0000 and out0 elsewise. I am just confused with how to do something with priority logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can redesign your code as:

```
always(posedge clock)
  if (reset) begin
    out0 <= 0;
    out1 <= 0;
  end
  else
    if ({in[3:0], in[13:4]} == 14'b0000_0000000001)
      out1<=in;
    else if ({in[3:0], in[13:4]} == 14'b0000_0000000010)
      out1<=in;
    else if ({in[3:0], in[13:4]} == 14'b0000_0000000100)
      out1<=in;
    else if ({in[3:0], in[13:4]} == 14'b0000_0000001000)
      out1<=in;
    else
      out0<=in;
```

or replace if/else to case

```
always(posedge clock)
  if (reset) begin
    out0 <= 0;
    out1 <= 0;
  end
  else
    case ({in[3:0], in[13:4]})
      14'b0000_0000000001: out1<=in;
      14'b0000_0000000010: out1<=in;
      14'b0000_0000000100: out1<=in;
      14'b0000_0000001000: out1<=in;
      default: out0<=in;
    enscase
```

Comment: Aha.. yea.. thanks for the suggestion. I shall try it out.